# MovieClip(root) line seems to be crashing my game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Inside my classes, I invoke this function

```
MovieClip(root).increaseScore();
```

which handles the score in the main .as file.
It all works fine during the execution of the level. However when the level is finished and the screen goes to another frame, the game crashes and gives me this error

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.

on the line above.

How do I fix this?
Thanks

edit:
This is were I tell it to addScore, this is in the GameController.as file

```
        private function removeBubble(bubble, addScore:Boolean)
        {
                var delay:Timer = new Timer(200, 1);
                delay.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, function(e:TimerEvent)
                {

                    if(bubble.parent==mcGameStage) 
                    {
                        var j:int = bubbleList.indexOf(bubble);
                        bubbleList.splice(j,1);
                        if(addScore) bubble.addScore();
                        mcGameUI.txtScorePlayer.text = String(playerScore);
                        mcGameStage.removeChild(bubble);
                    }
                e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);
                checkWin();
                });
                delay.start();
        }
```

here is the checkWin function:

```
        private function checkWin()
        {
            if (playerBlue + playerRed + playerYellow + playerOrange + playerPurple + playerGreen == 0)
            {
                gameWin();
            }
        }
        private function gameWin()
        {
            while (bubbleList.numChildren > 0) 
            {
                bubbleList.removeChildAt(0);
            }

            mcGameUI.btnMixBlue.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mixBlue);
            mcGameUI.btnMixRed.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mixRed);
            mcGameUI.btnMixYellow.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mixYellow);
            mcGameUI.btnNeedle.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, activateNeedle);
            mcGameStage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update);
            mcGameStage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkToHit);
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, gameAddedToStage ); 
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyDownHandler);
            stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,keyUpHandler);
            if (mouseCursor != null)
            {
                mouseCursor.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followMouse);         
                mouseCursor = null;
            }

            gotoAndPlay("level1win");

        }
```

And inside my classes,

```
public function addScore()
{
    root["increaseScore"]();
}
```

This is what increaseScore does

```
public function increaseScore()
{
    playerScore += 1000;
}
```

So where is the null object? D:
Also I am very inexperienced using the debugger so I apologize if this could be easily solved with that. I tried it and couldn't figure it out before coming here.
What is OPP method?
What is FrameScript?
Also, the class is MovieClip

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this is done with the help of the debugger!

The error is telling you that something is null and you're trying to access it. That's not good, so let's think what could be null?

1) Your movie clip instance might be null.
2) increaseScore() method of your movie clip instance might try to access something that is null

You didn't post any code that I could analyse at the time I'm writing this answer, so I can't say for sure.

Some possible problems:

Your class is not called MovieClip, but you're just trying to cast your root object to a MovieClip. Thing is, MovieClip's don't have a increaseScore() method. You should instead call the increaseScore() method with

```
root["increaseScore"]();
```

This will call the method of your root timeline, but since we are using weak-typing, you might have problems with debugging it later. But I guess that's the price you pay when writing all the code in a frame instead of using OPP approach.

Comment: @AndreyPopov I don't believe I've written anything fundamentally wrong after the first sentence. Sure, calling methods as dynamic objects is bad, but telling a person to re-write all the code to work beautifully as OOP is not going to help either :) Anyway, I think we can agree that frame-scripting is very prone to hacky solutions, so the best I can help with is to warn of the possible problems it can cause.

Comment: @AndreyPopov you know, on second thought, I think this debate is pointless - there's just not enough info to really answer a question. As the question is now it's just a guessing game, so either of us could be right; we just can't know that.

Comment: @CreativeMagic thanks for answering, I added more info and some code. Could you please look at it again? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The true reason here is said in the error: *Cannot access a property or method of a **null object reference**.*

What this means is that `MovieClip(root)` is null (it doesn't even bother to check if the function is present). The reasons for this might be three:

- Your document class is not MovieClip (could be Sprite).
- The class you use `root` in, is not `DisplayObject`. The property is part of the DislpayObject class and so if you use it on other kind of classes that does not extend it, it won't work.
- You are using this piece of code **before** you have added the instance to the stage (*most probable cause*). The root property represents the top-most display object in the tree. If you haven't added the child to the tree, it has no roots :) Check out `parent` - the error should be the same.

Comment: Honestly I don't think Document class or any class at all is being used here. It looks more like 100% frame-scripting and the code is being called from a nested timeline of some movie clip.

Comment: If he hasn't specified any document class, Flash will create his own internal one (and it will be MovieClip because of timeline). The other part is adequate - no matter where he uses the script, it must be in something that is **added** to the stage. As I said - it's not that the function is bad, but the root casted to MovieClip returns null. It's either not MovieClip or it's null (not added). Otherwise I agree that **if** this is frame script - it's a bad idea (it's even worse if you cast root in classes, but..) Cheers! :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov thanks for responding, I added some info and code to the post, could you please look at it again? :) thanks again